# What effect does a logic analyzer probe have on a circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, noise, probe, logic-analyzer

I have an MCU controlling a LED sign. This sign speaks the HUB75 protocol, which is essentially a large shift register. Being a shift register, this requires a clock signal to be generated, which the MCU appears to do just fine however the sign appears to not interpret it correctly. Annoyingly, connecting a logic analyzer and probe to the offending line causes all glitches to go away, and therefore I ask: what effect does placing a probe onto the signal cause?

I'm using a Saleae Logic 8 with it's built-in probes. The datasheet cites an "input capacitance" of 10pf, however the effect is not replicated with a 10pf cap to ground.

The circuit is running at 3v, but the logic analyzer is powered off of USB, so I'd assume it has 5v -- could this mean there's a pull-up somewhere? I'm running out of ideas, and so I asked here.

EDIT: I've done some more testing and the "fixing" effect (for lack of a better term) occurs even if the analyzer has no power, just ground and the signal itself.

Comment: (a) Is it a *real* Saleae Logic 8, or a "clone"? (b) Have you opened your specific analyser to view its actual input circuitry? If so, would you please edit your question and add some closeup, in-focus photos of the analyser PCB.

Comment: It is, in fact, a real Saleae bought straight off of their website and no I have not opened it up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. "*It is, in fact, a real Saleae*" OK, great, so in that case I'd suggest you ask Saleae, as it's a analyser-specific answer. It's always possible someone here knows (and will write) the answer for that specific analyser, but so will the manufacturer.

Comment: First just try a resistor of a few kilo ohms to ground.  As for the analyzer, a series resistor and then diode clamps to 3v3 and ground would be likely.

Comment: Exactly what logic is driving the clock, i.e. what MCU and what pin, and if it is configurable, what output type and current?  How long is the wire from the MCU to the sign?  What is the load presented by the sign, e.g. is it a single pin or multiple pins?  A probe can subtly change the timing, especially if there are problems from transmission line effects.

Comment: The clock is driven with DMA by a timer, so I'd assume it has fairly accurate timing. Furthermore, the "fixing" effect manifests even if I don't give the analyzer itself power. As soon as the ground is connected and the signal is connected to one of the channels the circuit works brilliantly.

Comment: @mincrmatt12 - Under an answer, you said: "*the signal gets better if I do things like change the wire length using a PCB*" That's new information. So in addition to attaching the logic probe being one workaround (I don't want to say "fix") for whatever the underlying problem is, another workaround is altering a wire length (which one(s))? If I was responsible for fixing this, I wouldn't be focusing on the logic analyser's exact input characteristics, since even if you duplicate those and the problems seem to stop, it'll only be a workaround. Instead, I'd do a design review of the schematics.

Comment: Buy our LED sign and we provide you with a free Saleae Logic 8.  What is the offending line.  What drives it?  How many inputs does it drive?  Line length?

Answer (score 1):

The noise is reduced not by the probe, but rather the earth gnd used by the probe.

The DC local circuit ground is probably floating with CM noise from SMPS.

I would connect 10nF from 0V to earth ground or inspect CM noise.

Comment: I'm fairly new to a lot of this, so forgive me if I've butchered something here, but if the problem was only with the ground signal, wouldn't just attaching the GND of my circuit to the analyzer fix it? This isn't the case and I've updated the question to reflect this information.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=common+mode+noise+reduction+user%3A17574

Comment: So grounding does not solve it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to test it, I don't have an earth ground coming out of my power supply (unless I'm being an idiot, which is quite possible, but I'm using a barrel jack which only has terminals for + and -), and therefore don't know where I'd place this 10nF cap.

Comment: Does Logic analyzer use earth ground, then just connect logic probe ground . If that works then DO as I said in answer. get an earth ground and Cap couple to it or do the other things.. i.e. is USB coming from an earth grounded tower or a laptop?  It may be your layout so shown pictures

Comment: The logic analyzer has a ground signal, but simply connecting it to my ground or coupling it with a cap doesn't do anything noticeable to the signal. Additionally I'm powering the thing through a breadboard until I get a PCB (the PCB was designed and ordered before I realized the circuit broke when the logic analyzer was removed), so could that be the culprit?

Comment: Could be . SHow a picture of all signals and grounds on cables. Run off a linear supply if possible to verify issues.  Measure ground noise with scope. or Audio IN with software scope

Comment: I'm unable to get a picture right now, but maybe I'll put this on hold since the PCB is getting put together tomorrow -- given the fact that the signal gets better if I do things like change the wire length using a PCB might solve the entire problem. Thanks for trying to help, though.

Comment: And use twisted pairs always when possible